# Problem with Amp Turn calculations for electromagnet

Tags: solenoid, electromagnet

I'm attempting to design an electromagnet, and the equations seemed to produce an nonsensical result.  The electromagnet needs to impart 42.75 newtons at 0.0015875 meters.  I needed to discern the Amp Turns required for a given soft iron core.

First I used this equation: F=(IN)<sup>2</sup> × Uo × A/(2g<sup>2</sup>).  Where Force is in newtons, IN = amp turns, Uo is the permability of air (1.25664 × 10<sup>-6</sup>), A is the cross sectional area of the core in meters squared (I used two core sizes of 5mm and 12.7mm), and g is the gap in meters.

I reworked it to this equation: IN<sup>2</sup> = F × (2g<sup>2</sup>)/(A * Uo) and came up with 2958 for IN for the 5mm core and 1162 for the 12.7mm core.

But this is for an air core.  So I plugged this answer into this equation: B = Uo * NI/L where L is the length in meters of the core.  I used a 12.7mm length core.  This gave me polar field strengths of 0.293 and 0.115 teslas (respectively).

I then used this equation: B=(Uo × Ur × IN)/L where Ur was the relative permeability of the core material (in this case a soft iron core with a Ur of ~86).  I rearranged the equation to: IN = B × L/(Uo × Ur).

This gave me 34.43 IN for the 5mm core and 13.51 IN for the 12.7mm core.  These numbers seem far too low to impart 42.75 newtons of force at the desired distance.  Before I buy the materials to assemble this I was hoping someone could either confirm that this number was in the ballpark, or show where I'd messed up.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Tip: You can use HTML entities `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, `&times;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts (but they don't work in the comments).

Comment: You know the Newtons. You can work out the maximum Tesla allowed for your soft iron core. So right at the point where the core ends and air begins, you can divide the Newtons by the allowable maximum Tesla (well) before saturation to work out the ampere-meter-turns that are required right at the surface. But, you have a distance from that surface. Since that air gap will almost certainly dominate your magnetic path length, divide by that distance away and you have the required ampere-turns. Which will be *huge*. Use *lots* of turns!!

Comment: Your final calculation is irrelevant because of the air-gap. The effective permeability of the core and air gap is pretty much what it is for air.

Comment: @jonk Dividing by the distance seems in error.  If I divided by .0001 meters I'd end up needing more amp turns than if I divided by .001 meters, despite the fact that the latter is ten times the distance of the former.

Comment: @Andyaka Didn't the first equation account for air gap?